# How to insert javascript inside a java scriplet in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

Here is my function:

```
var boxName = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
```

How can I put the value of boxName inside the scriplet like this?

```
<%BoxList.getInstance().getBoxListNames().contains(boxName);%>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Note that JavaScript and Java code run at different time. Also, you should not use scriptlets anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--Not Possible**

You might misunderstand that `jsp` and `javascript` existed on same document.Yes but JSP part compiles on server side itself comes to client.

Java script Plays on client side and `JSP` plays on server side.

What you need is you have to make a server request.And send that string a query parameter.

And please prefer to read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)